# Laravel Inserting multiple value inside same field

Tags: database, laravel, insert

I want my code to put put at least four of the values inside a single field named Member. I have tried to do this using the code below

Here is my code for the create.blade.php file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<form method="post" action="{{ route('group.store') }} "  >

{{csrf_field()}}


<select name=Member[] multiple size=4>
<input type="number" name="GroupID" placeholder="Group ID"><br></br>
<input type="text" name="Member" placeholder="Member 1" ><br></br>
<input type="text" name="Member" placeholder="Member 2" ><br></br>
<input type="text" name="Member" placeholder="Member 3" ><br></br>
<input type="text" name="Member" placeholder="Member 4" ><br></br>
</select>
<select name="Status">
    <option value="Official" name="Status">Official</option>
    <option value="UnOfficial" name="Status">UnOfficial</option>

</select>
<input type="text" name="Deadline" placeholder="Enter Deadline" ><br></br>

<select name="JudgementalView">
    <option value="Ongoing" name="JudgementalView">On going</option>
    <option value="Registered" name="JudgementalView">Registered</option>
    <option value="Completed" name="JudgementalView">Completed</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

```
@section('content')
```

Code for the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $storeInfo = new group();

    $storeInfo->GroupID = $request->input('GroupID');
    $storeInfo->Member= $request->input('Member');
    $storeInfo->Status= $request->input('Status');
    $storeInfo->Deadline = $request->input('Deadline');
    $storeInfo->JudgementalView = $request->input('JudgementalView');


    $storeInfo->save();




    return redirect('/group');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple option to save multiple option in single field.
I am showing one of those.
1. Add as an array
2. Add as comma separated. So when you will show this you need to convert into array

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {

   $storeInfo = new group();
   $storeInfo->GroupID = $request->input('GroupID');
   $storeInfo->Member= implode($request->input('Member'), ',');
   $storeInfo->Status= $request->input('Status');
   $storeInfo->Deadline = $request->input('Deadline');
   $storeInfo->JudgementalView = $request->input('JudgementalView');
   $storeInfo->save();
   return redirect('/group');
}
```